# Return closest date that is more than today from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array of Objects (below) and I am trying to figure out how to return the closest day from an array of objects that is more than todays date.

```
const poc = [
  {
    PartialRedemptionAmount: 2880000,
    PartialRedemptionDate: '2022-10-01T00:00:00Z',
    PartialRedemptionPrice: 100,
    PartialRedemptionType: 'UnscheduledRedemption',
  },
  {
    PartialRedemptionAmount: 2880000,
    PartialRedemptionDate: '2023-03-03T00:00:00Z',
    PartialRedemptionPrice: 100,
    PartialRedemptionType: 'UnscheduledRedemption',
  },
  {
    PartialRedemptionAmount: 2880000,
    PartialRedemptionDate: '2023-03-09T00:00:00Z',
    PartialRedemptionPrice: 100,
    PartialRedemptionType: 'UnscheduledRedemption',
  },
];
```

The datapoint I am trying to compare is`PartialRedemptionDate`

I tried doing a `some` since I need the the return object back that matches the criteria.

const closestDay = poc.some(poc)

any thoughts?

Comment: `poc.filter(old_days).sort(by_date)[0]`

Comment: You'll need to compare that date to todays date and then find the index with the lowest difference.

Comment: Closest in future or past or both?

Comment: local date or iso date? start of day or just 24h?

Comment: @marcel im looking closest date that is >= today’s date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Loop through the data

   1. Convert `PartialRedemptionDate` to todays date
   2. Check if it's lower then our remembered diff
   3. Overweite our flag if needed
   4. Return the object

```js
const poc = [{PartialRedemptionAmount: 2880000, PartialRedemptionDate: '2022-10-01T00:00:00Z', PartialRedemptionPrice: 100, PartialRedemptionType: 'UnscheduledRedemption', }, {PartialRedemptionAmount: 2880000, PartialRedemptionDate: '2023-03-03T00:00:00Z', PartialRedemptionPrice: 100, PartialRedemptionType: 'UnscheduledRedemption', }, {PartialRedemptionAmount: 2880000, PartialRedemptionDate: '2023-03-05T00:00:00Z', PartialRedemptionPrice: 100, PartialRedemptionType: 'UnscheduledRedemption', }, ];

const getClosestPoc = (data) => {
    let closestTime  = Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
        closestIndex = -1,
             current = Date.now();
             
    for (let o in data) {
        let obj = data[o];
        let diff = current - new Date(obj.PartialRedemptionDate).getTime();
        if (diff < closestTime) {
            closestTime = diff;
            closestIndex = o;
        }
    }
    return (closestIndex < 0) ? null : data[closestIndex];
};

const res = getClosestPoc(poc);
console.log(res);
```

Returns:

```json
{
  "PartialRedemptionAmount": 2880000,
  "PartialRedemptionDate": "2023-03-05T00:00:00Z",
  "PartialRedemptionPrice": 100,
  "PartialRedemptionType": "UnscheduledRedemption"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using filter, sort, and date.parse you can achieve this

filter to get dates that are more than today, and sort to sort by closest

change the expression in `.filter(obj => Date.parse(obj.PartialRedemptionDate) > Date.parse(today))` to get different condition either in the past or the future

```
const today = new Date().toISOString();

const closestDay = poc
  .filter(obj => Date.parse(obj.PartialRedemptionDate) > Date.parse(today))
  .sort((a, b) => Date.parse(a.PartialRedemptionDate) - Date.parse(b.PartialRedemptionDate))[0];

console.log(closestDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```js
function findClosestDateInFuture() {
  const now = new Date();
  return poc
    .filter(({ PartialRedemptionDate }) => new Date(PartialRedemptionDate) >= now)
    .reduce((smallestPocItem, pocItem) => { 
      if (!smallestPocItem) {
        return pocItem;
      } 

      const pocDate = new Date(pocItem.PartialRedemptionDate);
      const smallestPocDate = new Date(smallestPocItem.PartialRedemptionDate);
      return pocDate.getTime() < smallestPocDate
        ? pocItem
        : smallestPocItem;
    }, null);
}

function findClosestDateInPast() {
  const now = new Date();
  return poc
    .filter(({ PartialRedemptionDate }) => new Date(PartialRedemptionDate) < now)
    .reduce((smallestPocItem, pocItem) => { 
      if (!smallestPocItem) {
        return pocItem;
      } 

      const pocDate = new Date(pocItem.PartialRedemptionDate);
      const smallestPocDate = new Date(smallestPocItem.PartialRedemptionDate);
      return pocDate.getTime() > smallestPocDate
        ? pocItem
        : smallestPocItem;
    }, null);
}

function findClosestDate() {
  return poc.reduce((nearestPocItem, pocItem) => { 
    if (!nearestPocItem) {
      return pocItem;
    } 

    const pocDateDiff = Math.abs(new Date(pocItem.PartialRedemptionDate).getTime() - Date.now());
    const nearestPocDateDiff = Math.abs(new Date(nearestPocItem.PartialRedemptionDate).getTime() - Date.now());
    return pocDateDiff < nearestPocDateDiff
      ? pocItem
      : nearestPocItem;
  }, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the time with the current date and the current closest date in a loop, like the following.

```js
function getClosetData() {
  let closest = null;

  poc.forEach((item) => {
    if (new Date(item.PartialRedemptionDate) > new Date()) {
      if (!closest) {
        closest = item;

        return;
      }

      if (
        new Date(item.PartialRedemptionDate) <
        new Date(closest.PartialRedemptionDate)
      ) {
        closest = item;
      }
    }
  });

  return closest
}
```